# How to get the time of 5 minutes ago in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime, time

I'm using python to get time of 5 minutes ago.

Code:

```
import datetime
import time
now = datetime.datetime.now()

current_time = now.strftime(f"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

print(current_time)

2020-07-27 08:35:00
```

My question is how to get the time of 5 minutes ago.

something like

```
current_time-5mins
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You may use [**`datetime.timedelta()`**](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#module-datetime):

```
datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
```

Comment: Just a note that you may avoid repeating datetime.datetime by importing as follows: `from datetime import datetime, timedelta`